# How To Load and Unload Images In The Correct Manner

Tags: iphone, image, memory

I am having difficulty with images in my iPhone app. I load an image as follows:

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@""]];

CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
NSInteger texWidth = CGImageGetWidth(*imageRef);
NSInteger texHeight = CGImageGetHeight(*imageRef);
GLubyte *textureData = (GLubyte *)malloc(texWidth * texHeight * 4);
CGContextRef textureContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(textureData, texWidth, texHeight, 8,
                                          texWidth * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(*imageRef),
                                          kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);


CGContextDrawImage(textureContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (float)texWidth,
                                              (float)texHeight), *imageRef);
CGContextRelease(textureContext);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, location);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGBA,
                                       GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

free(textureData);
```

and I want to free all the memory that the image has used. I attempt to do that as follows:

```
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
free(image);
```

However, the memory does not appear to be freed according to Instruments. Am I missing something? Is it being cached by one of these functions? Furthermore, when I reload the image later, it appears to be loaded twice, i.e. the alpha channel is twice as much as it was the first time. And again, when I (attempt to) free the memory and come to reload it for a third time, the alpha channel is three times what it was the first time. The parts that are supposed to be almost transparent are becoming more and more opaque.

The issue with the transparency was not noticed in iOS 3, only iOS 4. But the issue with the memory not being freed was noticed in both.

Please can someone help me with this? I've spent so much time messing around with images! Also, I don't think I use a stupid amount of images: I am making a game that uses about 40 images, most of which are 128x128 PNGs. How come I run out of memory so quickly?? What is the "common" practice for this scenario? Am I right in trying to free the memory when the image isn't needed?

Replies will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should do:

```
[image release];
```

instead of

```
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

In fact the object that you are allocating is `image`, then you get a reference to one of its members; you do not need to release the reference to the member, but to the original object you allocated. You do not need calling `free(*image);`

EDIT:

All your usage of `*image` and `*imageRef` does not seem correct to me; you should use instead `image` and `imageRef`:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
NSInteger texWidth = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
NSInteger texHeight = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
GLubyte *textureData = (GLubyte *)malloc(texWidth * texHeight * 4);
CGContextRef textureContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(textureData, texWidth, texHeight, 8,
                                      texWidth * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef),
                                      kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

CGContextDrawImage(textureContext, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (float)texWidth,
                                          (float)texHeight), imageRef);
CGContextRelease(textureContext);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, location);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texWidth, texHeight, 0, GL_RGBA,
                                   GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);

free(textureData);
```

About memory consumption: I think that using the OpenGLES framework might exact a fixed penalty, i.e. increase the overall memory footprint of your app (due to loading the framework and instantiating I don't know which objects); but you should not experience an unexpected memory increase each time that you draw a texture.

Comment: I replaced the free with [image release], but the issue remains. It appears to be exactly as before. Any ideas?

Comment: Furthermore, when I release the image, I can still see it on the screen (it is the texture of an object). Do any of the openGL functions cache the image? Surely something has cached it, because it's still visible! Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: After even more investigating, I have found that the 512*512 PNG image has Size 86 KB on disk (in Finder). So why does it take up more than 3 MB of memory in the app? I ran Profiler/Instruments on it after removing the call to the function that loads this image (everything pasted above), and it was steady at 3.51 MB "Live Bytes" but if the function is called (it is definitely only called once, I have NSLogged it), then the "Live Bytes" becomes steady at 6.80 MB. Please help!! Why does it use up so much memory?

Comment: Hmm... actually, [image release] causes the app to crash with the error Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

Comment: Please, see my edit. I also have found this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411410/program-crashes-when-releases-uiimage-after-generating-opengl-es-texture . Please, try my change, and see whether it also helps reducing memory consumption.

Comment: Thanks sergio, please see my edit. It is actually in a function that I pass the **image, so I edited it to make it clearer in the original question, but missed a bit. The unloadImage function is also passed the **image. The use of the pointers is not the problem, otherwise I think I would have compilation errors. I looked at the link, thanks, it has resolved the issue with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I also saw http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/16616-opengl-garbling-image.html, I used calloc instead of malloc and so I no longer have the problem with alpha.

Comment: The only problem left is that it doesn't appear to free up any memory (in Instruments/Allocations "Live Bytes"). The whole point of loading the images lazily is to reduce memory consumption, but it doesn't appear to work at all.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to freeing up memory when using OpenGL is simple: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDeleteTextures.xml

Freeing the memory used by UIImage is barely noticeable compared to freeing the texture used by OpenGL. The problem lies in the following code:

```
GLuint textures[100]; // allows total of 100 textures

location = textures[imageNo];

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, location);
```

And it is solved by:

```
void unloadImage(GLuint imageNo)
{
    [textureImages[imageNo] release];
    glDeleteTextures(1, &textures[imageNo]);
}
```

I really hope this becomes useful to someone else using OpenGL textures on the iPhone, because it's had me going round in circles for ages!

And thanks to @sergio who helped with my issue!

Comment: This also means that you can release the UIImage immediately after CGContextDrawImage (i.e. you don't have to wait until you're actually finished with the image). This may be obvious to some, but I spent ages trying to figure out why the memory was not freed by releasing the UIImage!